# How can I add PHP to a Joomla menu item?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

Here's what I'm trying to do:

In Joomla 3.1, I'm using the K2 component to build a full content-driven news website.

All is well, but I just don't like the K2 Login module, and therein lies the rub. That module automatically generates two key links:

• Add Item
• My Page

I want to unpublish the login module and add both of these links to a standard Joomla menu. It's easy to add the "add item" link because it's essentially static.

But the "My Page" link is dynamic. I've found the PHP code that generates it:

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getUserRoute($user->id)); ?>"><?php echo JText::_('My Page'); ?></a>
```

But I don't know how to make a plain old Joomla menu item -- as in, one that I add through the menu manager -- to generate that code.

Note: It's important that I be able to use the Joomla menu structure because I'm also using Joomla's access control to hide or show these buttons. Meaning, I've added a "contributor" usergroup, and I only want them to see these links.

Any bright ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to the template you are currently using, in their you create a html folder. 
In that folder you create a mod_menu folder. 
Than you got your Joomla root > modules > mod_menu. 
And copy files which are inside and drop them in the html > mod_menu folder. 
Now you can edit the mod_menu to your favors with a rewrite.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Hope this helps you.